# Google Script: sending email as thread instead of individual emails

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

Currently have this script to send out approval request emails to relevant approvers. However would want for this to be sent out as a thread instead of spamming individual emails. Is there anything I could insert into my script to help with this? Thanks in advance!

```
function sendEmail(){

//drawing from the active sheet.
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  
//setting variables & getting the data from the sheet you are on
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();   // Number of rows to process
  var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn(); //Number of columns to process
  
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows-(startRow-1), numColumns);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  
  var complete = "sent";
  
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
  var row = data[i];
  var aemail = row[16]; //approver’s email
  var approval = row[13]; //approval column
  var reqrow = row[17]; //req row number
  var emailed = row[18]; //already emailed

//check to see if an email has NOT been sent      
    if (emailed != complete){
      
//check to see if not yet approved
    if(approval == ""){

//When done, it will mark it as sent in the last column
  var sent = sheet.getRange(startRow + i, numColumns); 

//Setting it to send the email to the approver's email
  var email = aemail;
          
//Change the text as desired
    var subject = "Quotation Request";
          
// \n is a line break
    var emailtext = "Hi, " +

    "\n\nYou have quotation request pending your review and approval on row " + reqrow + ".\n" +
    
    "\nPlease go to the link below for your further action.\n" +

    "\nhttps://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/x123/edit?usp=sharing \n" +

    "\nThis is an automated email. Thanks."

//Send the email    
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, emailtext); 
 
//Assign “sent” to to the last cell in the row so the email does not send again
      sent.setValue(complete);
    
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add parameter `Message-Id` in every email to achieve threading in recipient's mailbox.

However, GmailApp.sendEmail does not support this feature.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String)